# Getting image width using javascript have problem?

Tags: javascript, image, callback, size, width

This is the code i got from net to get the image width.
It works great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateDelegate(contextObject, delegateMethod)
{   
        return function()
            {
                return delegateMethod.apply(contextObject, arguments);
            }
}


function imgTesting_onload()
{
    image_width=this.width;
    alert(image_width);//First Alert
}
</script>
var imgTesting = new Image();
imgTesting.onload = CreateDelegate(imgTesting, imgTesting_onload);
imgTesting.src = "${str_applicationPath}/common/images/reports/"+report+".png"
//Second Alert//
```

But my need is to access the image_width variable at the //Second Alert// place in
the above code.I am not getting the width value there.Is anything to be done to
get value there?

Please Help Me.........
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you need it for? Like RoToRa said it's not possible so maybe we can help you find some way around your original need.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. At that point the width is not known. That is the whole point of the onload event in the first place. You have to execute the code you want at "Second alert" in imgTesting_onload instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **imgTesting.width** to get image width.

**For example:**

> var imgTesting = new Image();
>
> imgTesting.src => "${str_applicationPath}/common/images/reports/"+report+".png"
>
> //Second Alert//
>
> alert(imgTesting.width);

Below given code is not required

```
function CreateDelegate(contextObject, delegateMethod)
{   
        return function()
            {
                return delegateMethod.apply(contextObject, arguments);
            }
}
function imgTesting_onload()
{
    image_width=this.width;
    alert(image_width);//First Alert
}
imgTesting.onload =CreateDelegate(imgTesting, imgTesting_onload);
```

Comment: -1 Um, yes it is. The image load asynchronous so the width is most likely not known directly after setting `src`.